# Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts error when installing Blueprint

Tags: typescript, blueprintjs

I'm trying to use the `@blueprintjs/core` library in my project. However, when I compile my code, I'm getting many errors like this:

```
node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/dist/common/classes.d.ts(4,30):
  error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
```

What's going on? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of `@blueprintjs/core@1.7.0`, Blueprint is now compiled using TypeScript 2.1. With this new version of TypeScript, initializers are added to the emitted typings for constants.

So before, a line of the emitted `classes.d.ts` looked like this:

```
export declare const ACTIVE: string;
```

It now looks like this and includes an initializer:

```
export declare const ACTIVE = "pt-active";
```

This new syntax in declaration files makes old versions of the compiler unhappy. **To make the error go away, you'll need to make sure you're compiling your project with at least TypeScript 2.1.**

Comment: I used this answer after Cjo's and A.T.'s solutions and installed TypeScript 3.1 (upgrade from 3.0), only then the errors disappeared.

Comment: Upgrading TypeScript worked for me as well  Was trying to get [this Microsoft demo application for Teams](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node) up and running, and this was the key.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that you are writing code in a `d.ts` file. 
You should only be writing types in these "ambient" files. Things like initializing variables, writing functions, etc should not be done in "ambient" files.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem, but for me, updating the local (and global) *TypeScript* packages did *not* resolve the problem.  Luckily I came across the following article [Which version of TypeScript is Visual Studio Using?](http://www.allenconway.net/2015/07/which-version-of-typescript-is.html)

In a nutshell, whilst I had updated to *TypeScript 2.2*, Visual Studio was still referencing version 2.0 in the `.csproj` file.  I hope this helps someone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

For windows, to resolve this issue the shortest path is to install Typescript through installer.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Answer (score 2):

Delete your node-modules folder and do a clean installation.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue with a different library than blueprint.js that caused the ts compiler to throw "Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts" with an `index.d.ts` file that looks like this:

```
declare var identikon_cljs = require('identikon_cljs');
```

And I was able to get it to compile after adding or setting these properties to true in tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

Comment: The only option I needed is - "skipLibCheck": true. It stops Typescript checking 3rd party libraries in node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this issue.  Needed to download the latest version of typescript from typescript website and make sure 'use latest version' is selected in visual studio project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade typescript to at least 3.1+.

Comment: I have upgraded to 3.2. but its failed again

Answer (score -1):

> This error is because of node older version of node

You can remove the node version and reinstall it by using the below comand

```
rm -rf node_modules //For removing
npm install //Install again(Fresh with updated one)
```

Answer (score -3):

first update package.json with typescript version:3.6.4 and execute command npm i