# Error: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts

Tags: angular, node-modules, typescript2.0

I upgraded my Angular version from version 2.4.0 to 4.0.0 while compiling, I am getting following errors.

[image]

How can I resolve those errors?

Answer (score 2):

For me, this problem was caused by The Visual Studio project file referencing the wrong TypeScript compiler version - see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43963664/236860 and [Allen Conway's](http://www.allenconway.net/2015/07/which-version-of-typescript-is.html) excellent post.

Comment: Hi Neilski, I used the typescript latest version i.e 3.1 then am getting the issues.

Answer (score 0):

change the version of typescript to TypeScript 2.1.

This happens because there were breaking changes in typescript 2.1
Example :

```
declare const TEST_FIXTURE: string
```

now gets output as

```
declare const TEST_FIXTURE = "whatever";
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I'm using typescript 2.2. What should I do ?

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using Angular2 with typescript ^2.2.2 in Asp.net core. 
Any one with a suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Strange...did you do a npm clean and install ??  Can you post the line which causes error.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, here is detailed issue - 

     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394163/error-in-ionic-build-android-initializers-are-not-allowed-in-ambient-contexts

please any pointer

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. Global changes on TS version do not work, but when i change TS version to newest in devDependencies on package.json file, error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Just installing typescript solve the problem.

```
npm install -g typescript
```