# How to use Google DFP in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-dfp

I want to use Google DFP (Google Publisher Tag) but it does not working.

I defined global variable which holds `googletag`:

```
googletag: any =  window.googletag || {};
```

Adding the script to the page:

```
addGPTScript() {

  // Ad gtp.js script in the page
  const gads = document.createElement('script');
  gads.async = true;
  gads.type = 'text/javascript';
  const useSSL = 'https:' === document.location.protocol;
  gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
  const node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);

  if (this.googletag.apiReady) {
    console.log(this.googletag)
  }

  console.log(this.googletag)
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.addGPTScript();
}
```

But the first console.log in condition is never loaded and the second one prints `undefined`. I checked the HTML HEAD tag and found that script is added.

Comment: `declare var googletag: any =  window.googletag || {};` in `typings.d.ts`

Comment: @Chrillewoodz My IDE says "TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301181/initializers-are-not-allowed-in-ambient-contexts-error-when-installing-blueprint

Comment: @Chrillewoodz thanks. Do I need to add the lib/script in the HEAD and adding it through JS code also?

Comment: Should be able to have it in the body of the index.html, but then again I've never used that particular script so they might tell you otherwise.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I added in the head of document (without async attr) and added also through JS code and now the ` if (this.googletag.apiReady) {
    console.log(this.googletag)
  }` this works. But got `Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: "_this.googletag.googleTagletag is undefined"`. At least I have something to debug now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the following code was not working:

```
  // Ad gtp.js script in the page
  const gads = document.createElement('script');
  gads.async = true;
  gads.type = 'text/javascript';
  const useSSL = 'https:' === document.location.protocol;
  gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
  const node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
```

I removed the above and added in the HTML Head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
```

Comment: You know, that the first block is a javascript syntax and needs to be wrapped inside a HTML <script> tag, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing your output after the gpt.js has finished loading?
Put this in the line directly after declaring gads:

```
gads.onload = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(window.googletag)
}, 10);
```

Your loggings are meant to be be done just after appending the script to the DOM. It is not loaded then, it gets loaded async after executing your function and after your console.log calls.