# ERROR in node_modules/@angular/common/http/src/response.d.ts(253,21)

Tags: angular-cli

root@localhost:/var/www/html/abcd-seed# ng serve
    Your global Angular CLI version (7.1.2) is greater than your local
    version (6.2.8). The local Angular CLI version is used.

```
To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch 
false".
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, 
open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2018-12-10T14:35:22.329Z
Hash: 35a983178ac09d7b7950
Time: 25011ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.89 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 673 bytes 
[initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.22 kB [entry] 
[rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 311 kB [initial] 
[rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 329 kB [initial] 
[rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/common/http/src/response.d.ts(253,21): 
error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@angular/common/http/src/response.d.ts(259,19): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts(26,21): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/ivy_switch.d.ts(8,54): error TS1254: A 
'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric   
literal.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/ivy_switch.d.ts(9,35): error TS1254: A 
'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric 
literal.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/query_list.d.ts(36,22): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: best guess is that your typescript is out of date, can you post your package.json

Comment: Type Script version in package json.   "typescript": "3.0.3",

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts error when installing Blueprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301181/initializers-are-not-allowed-in-ambient-contexts-error-when-installing-blueprint)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale that answer wont help, im pretty sure the ts version needs updating

Comment: cmd: export declare const ACTIVE: string;  Error..  -bash: export: `ACTIVE:': not a valid identifier
Getting this error

Answer (score 2):

*Just deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and upgrade my project its working for me. i followed this https://medium.com/@jeroenouw/upgrade-to-angular-6-4520e46c682b*