# error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts

Tags: angular, google-api-nodejs-client

I have just created a new Angular CLI project and have added the Angular Material library.

My versions are as follows:

- node => 11.3.0
- npm => 6.7.0
- ng => 6.1.10
- googleapis => 36.0.0

I am trying to run `ng build` and continue to receive the above error message. Has anyone else run into this issue, and if so, how were you able to solve it?

It seems like there were some fixes by upgrading to the latest TS and/or removing and reinstalling your `node_modules`, but I have done each with no luck.

Comment: Did you try this? [Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts error when installing Blueprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301181/initializers-are-not-allowed-in-ambient-contexts-error-when-installing-blueprint)

Comment: Yes, and no luck. I have `typescript -v => 2.9.2`

Comment: Greetings!  With the Google libraries, you probably want to upgrade to the latest version of TypeScript.  We made a lot of changes that may not be backwards compatible with TypeScript 2.x.  It's probably a good idea to also update to v37 of the googleapis module ;)